# Kauth event upon start process. - prevention capabilities

Tags: macos, authorization, kernel-extension, darwin, xnu

I'd like to get event in kernel on each new process that starts (fork+execve or posix_spawn), and be able to prevent this operations.

The first option would be using Mac framework named `mpo_vnode_check_exec` by Hooking to this method with function that return 0 when access is granted or check deferred to next hook.. non zero returned value means access is refused right away.

Unfortunately, this framework is unsupported by apple, and I wish to use a stable alternative like kauth fileop scope with `KAUTH_FILEOP_EXEC` flag. 
However, this framework is for detection only and lacks prevention capabilities..

Perhaps there's a way to prevent the process from running when I get relevant kauth callback on process creation, or halt the process from running until I decide whether it should run or not (and enforce the verdict in another thread).

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, this framework is for detection only and lacks prevention capabilities..

Correct, if you're only focussing on the File scope.

[Register](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2127/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003591-CH1-SECTION3) with the [Vnode scope](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2127/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003591-CH1-SUBSECTION11) and your callback returns whether or not access is allowed.

```
kauth_listen_scope(KAUTH_SCOPE_VNODE, &myCallback, NULL);
```

Finally, note that this scope is very noisy, as every type of access to every resource is reported.

Comment: Hi and sorry for the late response, In order to decrease the noise, and if I only care about new processes, can I use the flag `KAUTH_VNODE_EXECUTE` ?

Comment: Yes, you can filter on the File Operation Scope